# Обрезается часть запроса GET при передачи данных на загрузку пикселя

Tags: php, javascript, json, get, lazyloading

Обрезается часть запроса GET при передачи данных на загрузку пикселя. Речь идет о скрипте, внутренней метрики для ряда сайтов на независимых друг от друга доменах. При загрузке скрипта происходит генерация запроса пикселя с центрального сервера с передачей основных параметров о посещении. Загрузка пикселя происходит такой строкой:

`new Image().src = "http://site.ru/monitor/widget/p.php?rf="+document.referrer+"&s="+JSON.stringify(cl)+"&v="+getRandomInt(0,999999999);`

В итоге получается загрузка пикселя по такой ссылке:

`http://site.ru/monitor/widget/p.php?s={%22ui%22:%22f458b41c-e4d3-4335-bca3-4c043fe942e8%22,%22si%22:%225bba364a-52c6-42bd-92b8-592b3a66b73b%22,%22cu%22:%22http://site.ru/monitor/index2.html%22,%22tt%22:%22Test.%20Only%20test.%22,%22rf%22:%22http://plus.url.google.com/url?sa=j&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsite.ru%2Fmonitor%2Findex2.html&uct=1533659578&usg=qNrROFw6qB42IV-ax53_lwOlF9U.%22}&v=71150`

Где на сервере принимается таким образом:

```
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postData, true);
```

Доступ к параметрам из json по типу:

```
$data['st']
```

Но, параметр `rf` обрезается до вида `http://plus.url.google.com/url?s`

Как правильнее сформировать запрос или как его правильнее принять, что бы все параметры приходили целиком?

Спасибо.

Comment: Попробовал разобрать Вашу ссылку на url-параметры, но адекватно сделать не вышло (скопировал код, вытащил всё что после первого `?`, а дальше функцией `parse_str` попытался разобрать на массив url-параметров, но не вышло. По всей видимости есть ошибки в формировании адреса запроса. Попробуйте обернуть `document.referrer` и `JSON.stringify` функцией `encodeURIComponent(string)`

Попробуйте на php сформированную ссылку разобрать таким образом:

`$url = 'ваша_ссылка';

$params = parse_url($url);

parse_str($params['query'], $url_params);

print_r($url_params);`

Comment: Видимо это то, что нужно. Завтра проверю и отпишусь. Спасибо.

Comment: Да. Сработала обвертка ссылки реферрера в encodeURIComponent.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, [PhoEn-X](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/18408/phoen-x).

Правильный ответ обернуть ссылку в  encodeURIComponent.

В итоге правильная конструкция запроса:

```
new Image().src = "http://site.ru/monitor/widget/po.php?rf="+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+"&s="+JSON.stringify(cl)+"&v="+getRandomInt(0,999999999);
```